# Scraping website without specific address

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a website that does not generate specific web address for the different pages I want to scrape. The reason for this is that each page is generated by selecting different options on some combo boxes, which thereafter produces the desired table.
Is is possible to scrape these tables using R and rvest?

EDIT:

Here is the link with a specific example:
http://www.odepa.gob.cl/precios/precios-al-consumidor-en-linea

Comment: Not in a straight up simple way...

Comment: Added a specific example to see if the specifics provide any help for an R solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium webdriver, to control clicks and dynamic data in html pages.

Try this : https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium

Comment: Would an R solution be possible?

Comment: If you want to scrape dynamic data and automate clicks, you'll have to use selenium.